# Do'nt show again Guide Activity when Aplication start

Tags: java, android

I develop android apps. I want my apps there guide when first installed. and the guide will disappear when I press the Start Application button. when the application back at the local launch the guide will not reappear. Thanks Before :D

Comment: What have you tried? Anyway, my idea on this is to create a local properties which you should check every time you start the application. A flag with a boolean value. If it is equal to 0, do not show the message. Otherwise, show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use shared preferences, see my answer to: [Shared Preferences in View Page Indicator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19095585/shared-preferences-in-view-page-indicator/19096035#19096035)

Store a boolean when user press the button, if the boolean is set, you can skip the guide.

Will work for the lifetime of the app installation.

First create the PreferencesData class (kept the String methods from link and added boolean ones)

```
public class PreferencesData {

    public static void saveString(Context context, String key, String value) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    sharedPrefs.edit().putString(key, value).commit();
    }

    public static String getString(Context context, String key, String defaultValue) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    return sharedPrefs.getString(key, defaultValue);
    }


    public static void saveBoolean(Context context, String key, Boolean value) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    sharedPrefs.edit().putBoolean(key, value).commit();
    }

    public static Boolean getBoolean(Context context, String key, Boolean defaultValue) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    return sharedPrefs.getBoolean(key, defaultValue);
    }
}
```

Now, in your MainActivity (I assume you have a MainActivity and a GuideActivity here)

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     // will return the default value true if never been set before
     if (PreferencesData.getBoolean(this, "showGuide", true) {
         startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, GuideActivity.class));

         // you can do this from the last step of your guide instead
         // to make sure that the guide is shown again if user 
         // quit before completing it

         PreferencesData.saveBoolean(this, "showGuide", false);

         finish();
     } else {
          // continue application
          setContentView(R.id.yourlayout);
          ...
     }
 }
```

Comment: how to I apply to my apps...
sorry I'm newbie :(

Comment: I still feel confused about how to apply sharedpreference into the button. but thank you for the information shared her :)

Comment: No problem. Regarding the button, you just change the showValue to false in onClick of the button. This save/get method can be used anywhere in your app, so don't worry about where to use it. Simply do where you need it, as long as you have a context to hand it

Answer (score 0):

Set the walkthrough guide as the app's main activity, but before you instantiate any layout for that activity, check for the presence of a flag that says whether or not the guide has been dismissed once before. This flag needs to be somewhere that stays around when the app is closed - either in a properties file or a database. The first time a user dismisses the guide, set that flag to true; the next time you check it on startup, you'll be able to skip the layout for the walkthrough and send your app straight to its first "real" activity.

**EDIT:**
Beaten to it. Yes - use SharedPreferences unless you already have a database setup you'd rather use.

Comment: If you did not make the edit he might not notice and accept you answer :P it is afterall equally true, though I personally chose to start the guide from my main activity, both because it is an exception rather than standard to be loaded in the first place, and because I have a splash screen, which my main activity is responsible for creating (plus background preloading etc.)